# Getting column where x meets condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I retrieve the column name for the value that fits the condition.
I am looking to loop through every value, if the value is <= to 1 return the column name

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 5),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'])

for item in df.iteritems():
  for x in item[1]:
    if x <=1:

        print(df4.column,x)
```

Comment: Please clearly indicate your expected output. You are generating random float numbers, and it will be very difficult to generate any exactly equal to 1 in this small sample. Please fix your [mcve].

Comment: I am looking to loop through every value, if the value is <= to 1 return the column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code a bit, with a slight change to work

This code will print you the name of the column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

for col, values in df.iteritems():
    for x in values:
        if x <= 1:
            print(col, x)
```

This code will print you the entire column in the DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

for col, values in df.iteritems():
    for x in values:
        if x <= 1:
            print(df[col], x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is iterate through the entire Dataframe, and print out the column where your condition is true.

**Code**

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
        if column>=1:
            print(j)
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do but your iteration isnt given me the column name just the row value

Comment: There you go, I edited the code. Now it will show the column name.